# What is the official method to stack columns on mobile but not on desktop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v. 4 for the first time and I have a footer that, on desktop, has three rows, and inside that two columns with an icon in the left column and text on the right.

But on mobile I want the icon to appear on top of the text. I know I could add a `div` with a `row` class to achieve this, but then that would affect desktop as well.

I tried researching a solution but either a proper / official one doesn't exist or I'm not using the right search terms.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

```
    <div class="col" id="kpc-phone-address-booking">

      <h2>Contact</h2>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <p><a href="tel:<?php echo get_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_phone_1', 'option'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_phone_1', 'option'); ?></a></p>
          <p><a href="tel:<?php echo get_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_phone_2', 'option'); ?>"><?php echo the_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_phone_2', 'option'); ?></a></p>
        </div>

      </div>



      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><?php echo the_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_address', 'option'); ?></p>
        </div>

      </div>



      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <p><a href="<?php echo get_field('kpc_site_wide_fields_schedule_an_appointment_url', 'option'); ?>">Schedule an Appointment »</a></p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: By default, columns *always* stack and become full-width on the `xs` breakpoint (mobile widths <576px). In Bootstrap 4, `xs` is the implied breakpoint, so you just need to use `col-*` (no longer `col-xs-*`)

---

**2 important things to know about the Bootstrap grid:**

1. You can put more than 12 units of columns in a single `.row`. This is known as [column wrapping](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#column-wrapping). When the columns exceed 12 they "wrap" to a new line.

So, if you change the markup to...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="kpc-phone-address-booking">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <p><a href="-">Option</a></p>
                    <p><a href="-">Option</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <p itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">Option</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <p><a href="">Schedule an Appointment »</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You'll see it works the same way on desktop eventhough the `.row`s have been removed. This is becaase 3+9=12, so each combo of 3+9 will "wrap" to the next line.

http://www.codeply.com/go/1cjoPMdpmd

2. **Columns always stack, and become full-width on the xs breakpoint** (<576px). Basically `col-12`, is *implied* even when not specified. Use a specific `col-*` (xs) class to *prevent* the stacking.

For example, if your columns were changed to `col-3` and `col-9` they would *not* stack vertically at widths <576px. When you resize the [demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/1cjoPMdpmd) to a narrow screen width <576px notice that the columns stack vertically and become full width. However, I changed the last 2 columns to:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-2">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-10">
            <p><a href="">Schedule an Appointment »</a></p>
        </div>
```

Which will `prevent` these last 2 columns from stacking vertically. They will scale down in width as the screen width shrinks < 576px.